# como encriptar un controlador de php

Tags: php, laravel

Por petición del cliente se a pedido que se tenga una versión del documento controlador A y/o B.

Estoy entiendo que con el fin de compartir con agencias (u otros des arrolladores)  el código, pero de manera parcial y funcional. Es decir que el programador A tenga acceso al controlador que involucra reportes y respuestas a cliente, que el programador B tenga acceso al controlador que involucra nominas sin restringir la funcionalidad normal de la herramientas (para que si cambian algo no afecte por error el funcionamiento general).

Yo utilizo normal mente para html y front php una aplicación en una pagina que al introducir el código me entrega el codigo cifrado con contraseña. Se que hay otras opciones en linea pero quisiera saber cual es la mas eficiente.

E investigado por opciones de codificación como base64 que ofuscar el codigo.
 blenc_encrypt que funciona un poco mas sencillo:

```
blenc_encrypt($source_code, "my_source_encoded.php", ini_get('blenc.key_file'));
```

Pero entiendo que no tiene que ser muy complejo (por ahora y por cuestiones de tiempo.)

Mi documento controlador esta en un proyecto Laravel, dentro de la carpeta de controller.

gracias

Comment: Esta no es la manera de hacer lo que quieres, deberíais hacer una API en lugar de entregar controladores, que ademas de estar todo preparado para hacerlo, la encriptacion no es segura, dado que para usarla deberán desencriptarla igualmente, por lo que es como si no hicierais nada. Otra opción es ofuscar el código, pero eso solo hace que sea difícil de leer y al final es igualmente desofuscable. Porque no hacéis simplemente paquetes y usais git?

Comment: no me es familiar lo que mencionas de paquetes, y no e usado git jeje, podrías describir un poco mas el poseso que mencionas. me suena muy interesante.

Comment: Al igual que usas las librerías que pones en tu composer.json, puedes hacer las tuyas propias (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages). No es muy complejo, pero tampoco es para alguien que acabe de empezar. Respecto a lo de git, es mas que nada porque al hacer paquetes puedes poner distintas versiones en tu composer.json facilmente (ademas de que es una locura ser programador sin usar un control de versiones)

Comment: gracias, lo estoy implementando

Comment: funciono bien!, disculpa podrías postear tu respuesta mas abajo para poder aceptarla? gracias :)

Comment: Algún moderador me la puso como comentario, voy a ver si me dejan recuperarla